# Best way to send 10,000 doubles over HTTP

Tags: iphone, google-app-engine, ios, ios4, double

I have a client application (iPhone) that collects 10,000 doubles. I'd like to send this double array over HTTP to an appengine server (java). I'm looking for the best way to do this.

Best can be defined as some combination of ease of programming and compactness of representation as the amount of data can be quite high.

My current idea is that I will convert the entire array of doubles to a string representation and send that as a POST parameter, on the server parse the string and convert back to a double array. Seems inefficient though...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that there are lots and lots of different ways to do this. If it were me I would probably just serialize to an array of bytes and then base64 encode it, most other mechanisms will significantly increase the volume of data being passed.

Comment: any sample code on serialization to byte array then base64 encoding then deserialization?

Comment: (have searched google for converting double array to byte array in objective c but no luck)

Comment: There's no need to base64 encode them - binary data is fine in the body of a POST request.

Answer (score 4):

I think you kind of answered your own question :) The big thing to beware of is differences between the floating point representation on the device and the server. These days they're both going to be little-endian, (mostly) IEEE-754 compliant. However, there can still be some subtle differences in implementation that might bite, e.g handling of denormals and infinities, but you can likely get away with ignoring them. I seem to recall a few of the edge cases in NEON (used in the iPhone's Cortex A-8) aren't handled the same as x86.

If you do send as a string, you'll end up with a decimal and binary conversion between, and potentially lose accuracy. This isn't that inefficient, though - it's only 10,000 numbers. Unless you're expecting thousands of devices pumping this data at your server non-stop.

If you'd like some efficiency in the wire transfer and on the device side, then one approach is to just send the doubles in their raw binary form. On the server, reparse them to a doubles (Double.longBitsToDouble). Make sure you get the endian-ness right when you grab the data as longs (it'll be fairly obvious when it's wrong).

Answer (score 1):

10k doubles is 80k binary bytes is about 107k or so characters base64 encoded.  Or 3 doubles is 24 binary bytes is 32 base64 characters.  There's tons of base64 conversion example source code available.

This is far preferable to any decimal representation conversions, since the decimal conversion is slower and, worse, potentially lossy.

Answer (score 0):

json

for iphone encode with yajl-obj-c

and for java read with jsonarray

Comment: Any idea on how efficient this method is in terms of size? It certainly is easy to implement, just not sure how big the data transfer will be....

Answer (score 0):

If you have a working method, and you haven't identified a performance problem, then the method you have now is just fine.

Don't go trying to find a better way to do it unless you know it doesn't meet your needs.

On inspection it seems that on the java side, a double (64 bytes) will be about 4 characters (16 bytes * 4). Now, when I think of your average double, let's say 10 digits and a decimal point, plus some delimiter like a space of semicolon, you're looking at about 12 characters per decimal. That's only 3x as much.

So you originally had 80k of data, and now you have 240k of data. Is that really that much of a difference?

Comment: agree with you - but don't have a working solution. Before coding the string method, wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious

Comment: My mistake, it does say "current idea", where I read "current method". Regardless, I would stick to what is simple easy to code (and debug!) until you have a performance problem. I think the math in this post is fairly accurate to show it's not that big of a performance hit to use strings.